# ElasticSearch 2.1 "aggs" is not a valid parameter

Tags: php, rest, elasticsearch, parameters

I did the following rest request and it's working

```
{
  "aggs": {
    "gender": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "gender"
      }
    }
  },
  "size": 0
}
```

But when i do it in PHP with array like this:

```
['aggs' => [
        'gender'  => [
            'terms' => [
                'field' => 'gender'
            ],
        ],
    ],
];
```

I'm getting the following error :

```
{
code: 500,
message: ""aggs" is not a valid parameter. Allowed parameters are: "analyzer", "analyze_wildcard", "default_operator", "df", "explain", "fields", "from", "ignore_unavailable", "allow_no_indices", "expand_wildcards", "indices_boost", "lenient", "lowercase_expanded_terms", "preference", "q", "query_cache", "request_cache", "routing", "scroll", "search_type", "size", "sort", "source", "_source", "_source_exclude", "_source_include", "stats", "suggest_field", "suggest_mode", "suggest_size", "suggest_text", "timeout", "version", "fielddata_fields", "filter_path", "client", "custom", "filter_path"",
errors: [ ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show the PHP code you use to send your aggregation query?

Comment: Cool, glad you figured it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution, it was a problem in the code PHP

We are using a Framework Majora, and we are only returning Queries from ElasticSearch to a response.

So i will fix that for the Aggregation to return aggs in the response.

Thanks